# Issue regarding with "and" operator in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have  a program like this:

```
a="string"
for i in a:
    if i>97 and i<122:
         print "lower case"
```

But print statement does not give output or error. why?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You are encouraged to display and indent your code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing character and number in your `if` statements.

Strings are compared *lexicographically*, and dissimilar types are compared by the name of their type `("int" < "string")`

Use `ord(i)`

```
a = "string"
for i in a:
    if 97 < ord(i) < 122 :
        print "lower case"
```

Or you can use: `islower()` to check lowercase

```
a = "string"
for i in a:
    if i.islower():
        print "lower case"
```

Comment: Note that `97 < ord(i) < 122` is more readable and, as `ord` only gets called once, more efficient. Also Python has a string method for determining if it's lower case.